# How to enable popups in QWebView? [Qt]

Tags: qt, qtwebkit, qwebview, qwebpage

I have a very simple Qt Application which uses QtWebkit and QWebPage to render webpages. The problem is that it doesn't seem to support popups. For example, in google.com, when I click on "Gmail", a Javascript alert say that my browser has disabled the popups...

And a html file with the following "a" tag: `<a href = "index.html" target = "_blank">Link</a>` works neither.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to redefine either `QWebPage::createWindow` or `QWebView::createWindow` to create a new `QWebPage` and/or `QWebView`.